# Aborting Jenkins pipeline stage without aborting subsequent stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

## Question

I have a Jenkins pipeline with multiple stages.  These stages are executed on separate worker nodes.  Currently when I abort a pipeline the subsequent stages are all aborted and the build status is set to aborted.

I would like to develop the pipeline such that I can abort a stage without aborting all subsequent stages.

## Build Log

Below is a sample build log of a pipeline with two stages: Stage A and Stage B.  As you can see when I aborted Stage A Jenkins skips Stage B.  I would like Jenkins to execute Stage B when Stage A is aborted

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (A)
[Pipeline] echo
Started stage A
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 20 sec
Aborted by anonymous
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (B)
Stage "B" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: ABORTED
```

Answer (score 1):

## Clarification

Your question isn't very clear.  My understanding is that you wish to structure you pipeline such that if Stage A is aborted it will still run Stage B.  To do this you need to use the [catchError](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#catcherror-catch-error-and-set-build-result-to-failure) step.  Sample code is included below

> The catchError step behaves differently than a try/catch block so please read the linked documentation

## Code Sample

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("A") {

            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'ABORTED') { 
                    echo "Started stage A"
                    sleep(time: 20, unit: "SECONDS")
                }
            }
        }

        stage("B") {
            steps {
                echo "Started stage B"
                sleep(time: 20, unit: "SECONDS")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Build Log

The following build log illustrates me aborting the pipeline in Stage A, but Jenkins continues onward past catchError and executes Stage B.

```
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Testing/sleep-abort-test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (A)
[Pipeline] catchError
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
Started stage A
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 20 sec
Aborted by Chris Maggiulli
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // catchError
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (B)
[Pipeline] echo
Started stage B
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 20 sec
Click here to forcibly terminate running steps
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: ABORTED
```